# Syntax Error in Python print

Tags: python, printing

While running this piece of code in python/linux:

```
import numpy as numpy
import cv2
import os

os.system('clear')
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('vid_1.mp4')

q = 0 
while(cap.isOpened()):
   ret, frame == cap.read()
   if ret == True:
      q += 1  
      print("Frame No: " + q)


   gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
   cv2.imshow('frame',gray)

   if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
      break

      cap.release()
      cv2,destroyAllWindows()
```

I encountered the following error:

```
 print("Frame No: " + q)
                      ^
 IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

In addition, **os.system('clear')** seem not to be clearing the screen. I assume sth basic missing, what could it be please? Thanks

Comment: The code your pasted isn't valid because the `while` block isn't indented.

Comment: Sorry, I did not indent the code while putting it into the question section. It is now done. thanks for the remind

Answer (score 0):

```
if ret == True:
   q += 1  
   print("Frame No: " + q)
```

It appears that that line of code is indented only two spaces in, while the other lines are indented four spaces in.

```
if ret == True:
     q += 1  
     print("Frame No: " + q)
```

Would this work?

Comment: Can I know how much should be the indenting for while, if etc in my code?

Comment: Any amount can be fine. Just make sure that each line (if needed) is indented the same amount. In your code, some lines were indented 2 spaces in, but others were indented 4 spaces in. If you're using IDLE, it should tab in 4 spaces each time by default. @YAS

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You're mixing tabs and spaces, which confuses Python. Use one or the other, not both. Spaces are preferable.

Comment: Sure, my original code was edited. The problem still remains. Can you tell me about indenting in python?

Comment: Problem solved !  **ret , frame ==cap.read()** should have changed to **ret , frame =cap.read()** and also **print("Frame No: " + q)**  to **print("Frame No: " , q);**